# Is there a recommended path to save files on SD Card?

Tags: android

I see files from apps all over in the sd card so there doesn't seem to be an android standard. But when saving app related files externally, is there a recommended directory path to use or a common practice?

ie. (sdcard)/myapp/ or (sdcard)/apps/myapp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) with the various String types for a specific folder.

This creates folders in `.../sdcard/Android/data/my.package.name/<type>`.

From the [Developer's Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> In API Level 8 or greater, use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), passing it the type of public directory you want, such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC, DIRECTORY_PICTURES, DIRECTORY_RINGTONES, or others. This method will create the appropriate directory if necessary.
>
> If you're using API Level 7 or lower, use getExternalStorageDirectory() ...

Comment: This seems to be the right way to do it but not everyone is since there's files scattered all over my sd card even the root

Answer (score 2):

You should first off use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

To figure out the sdcard location. From there typically it is just your appname as the folder to store any files in. Or so that appears to be the standard looking at my phone.

Comment: @Jack You can find more from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Android/data/" + yourpackagename;
```

if you check this file, you can see lots of apps here.